# Why does the toolbar disappear when the background of the fragment is set to a certain color?

Tags: android

I'm working on a drawer layout. I want to replace the main activity screen with a fragment when I click a menu item, but it doesn't show a toolbar when I set the background of a fragment on some color app. Work done so far ...

```
<!-- activity_main.xml-->  

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:background="#ff9100"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:title="News Time"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            />
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/replacer"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navmenu"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navheader"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#ffaa00"
        />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.newsapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    NavigationView nav;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        nav = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navmenu);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.open,R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

         final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
         final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


        nav.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                Fragment temp = null;
                switch (menuItem.getItemId())
                {
                    case R.id.sporticon:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This is sport section",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        temp = new sportfragment();
                        break;
                }
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.replacer,temp);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is fine when there is no background attribute but toolbar disappears when I add it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".sportfragment"
    android:background="#00c3ff"
    >

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is sport section"
   />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using relative layout so you have to position every single child in relative layout since you are not doing it. framelayout overlapping the toolbar when there is not color in framelayout toolbar visible to you and it does not go anywhere so whenever you add a color toolbar becomes invisible to you but not from screen it will be under the framelayout...
so add below line in framelayout

```
android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
```